# Mysql alias and date function fails

Tags: mysql, date, alias

I have a datetime field in one table that I want to retrieve using date in order to remove the time. The query contains multiple joins so I need to use aliases but that is not working. For example, this works

```
    SELECT date(mydate) FROM mytable
```

but this doesn't

```
    SELECT date(o.mydate) FROM mytable o
```

The above fails with "Unknown column 'o.mydate' in 'field list'"

Is there a way to use an alias in a function like this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue (and didm't expect to). https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3f6d804d912381b6daafa35d6e20595f please add table definition and sample data

Comment: Yes, that's fine (I tested it as well). A possible problem is that the `o` you defined as the table alias is not the same `o` symbol you used in the select-list expression. For example, unicode characters can look identical to ascii characters, yet be different characters. Try re-typing the query and be careful to use the same characters in both references to the table alias.

Comment: I created a test table and the command worked. Tried it again on the original table and it worked too. :( I guess I must have typed it wrong, though I tried many times. Thank you both for taking a look.